# PHP Show size of file without being uploaded

Tags: javascript, php

I want t make a PHP site that Show size of file without being uploaded
actually i want to show the size of file that the clint want to upload
Try code in PHP and Javascript

Comment: PHP cannot know anything about the file before you upload it to the server. You need JS to implement this functionality.

Comment: "I want t make a PHP site that Show size of file without being uploaded" - This can not happen

Comment: Use the JavaScript on the front end